# Differences Between Classes of ＊过 Verbs ( 通过, 经过, 透过, 穿过, etc. )

Tags: word-choice, difference, preposition

### Original Question

Although 通过 is the goto expression for passage through or across a space in informal, spoken Mandarin, there are specific alternatives used in more formal, spoken Mandarin as well as in writing.  <strike>This question serves to provide the community with a comprehensive list.</strike>  **EDIT:** *As "comprehensive list" questions are frowned upon on the StackExchange network, this question's purpose shall be to illustrate the classes of ＊过 verbs.*

#### Examples

通过 to go through something in a general or abstract sense
经过 to go past something; **EDIT:** *or to pass something*
透过 through, via, or by way of something
穿过 to go through a structure such as a tunnel or hallway
*Consider the sense of piercing or penetration that comes from* 穿

<strike>What additional situation-specific alternatives to 通过 exist?</strike>
**EDIT:** *What classes of ＊过 verbs exist?*

Comment: 通过 is absolutely formal.Both of these have specific  contexts.There are lots of words can be used  with 过 to express "through something".like 闪过，盖过，突过，铺过，折过。

Comment: 经过 to go ***pass** something

Comment: @PeteC. OP is correct, it should be "to go past something" (you can check out http://english.stackexchange.com/a/51341) but it is "to pass something" here's something to confuse everyone: I went past my friend's store today. I passed (by) my friend's store today. Did you go past my friend's store too?

Comment: @Ming OK my bad :)

Comment: @PeteC. no worries, native English speakers get that mixed up too, it's a common problem :) Notice when 'past' is used, it has a verb before it (went, go) but with 'pass/passed', it is being used as a verb itself. Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, `过`, by itself, mainly has two meanings:

1. to pass (as a verb), e.g.: 过江(to pass a river)
2. mistake (as a noun), e.g.: 大过(a serious mistake)

I guess in this question you are more interested in the first one and will share my two cents on that.

I can see two dimensions for classifying the `*过` words of the sort that you mentioned:

- How `to pass` what is to be passed

  It depends on the meaning of the `*`:

  1. through it: 通过, 穿过, 透过 etc.
  2. outside of it and without (or at least not emphasizing) touching it: 经过, 越过, 超过 etc.
  3. outside of it and touching (or making one feel that it almost touched) it: 扫过, 擦过, 拂过 etc.
- How abstractable the word is

  (Let's ignore literary innovations for this case)

  1. the great majority of the words are mostly restricted to their  space-related literal meaning: 穿过, 越过, 超过, 扫过, 擦过, 拂过 etc.
  2. a few of them can be extended to the time dimension (to `pass` a period or an event): 经过, 度过 (note: in modern Chinese, `度过` can only mean `to pass a period or an event`, its space-related counterpart is `渡过`)
  3. some other few of them can be abstracted to mean `by means of`: 通过, or `to look through something (to observe)`: 透过 as in `透过现象看本质` (to look through the phenomena to observe the essence)

After finishing writing the stuff above it suddenly occurred to me that there's another usage of `过` that's also relevant:

adj. + `过`: to be more adj. than

e.g.: 好过 (to be better than), 热过 (to be hotter than), etc.

You may deem them as being abstracted by nature.

Answer (score 1):

2 alternatives in an abstract sense: iciba： 以（介）：例句：他～自学完成了大学全部课程，

征求（动）：（有关的人或组织的同意或核准）：这问题要～群众，才能做出决定。